# Numpy subclassing: Create a copy of an array with different shape, same metadata

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a subclassed numpy array - a "spectroscopic axis" with metadata such as units.

I can create a copy of any instance using `arr.copy` or a view using, e.g., `arr2=arr[2:5]`.

Is there any way to create a new instance of one of these arrays *with a different shape* but keeping the same metadata / data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define a `.reshape` method in your subclass. This `.reshape` method should call the `__array_finalize__` method that would be in charge of copying the metadata from your object.

For example, the `MaskedArray` subclass uses a `_update_from` private method that copies some metadata (`_fill_value`, `_optinfo`...) from one object to another or sets defaults for these metadata if they are not yet available. The `_update_method` is called within `__array_finalize__`. You could follow the [sources](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py) as an example.

Comment: I think all I need is an _update_from method.  It's non-trivial: I have to specify which attributes to inherit, but it works.

Comment: If your subclass has a `__dict__`, you could start by ensuring that it is properly copied in `__array_finalize__`. You probably don't need the whole `_update_from`.